# where do people put their pivot tables when they made an excel dashboard

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dashboard

I am creating a dashboard in excel and need pivot charts and tables for it. For this, I put each pivot chart on separate sheets. I was wondering if this is how it’s done as all the dashboard examples I have seen do not have the extra pivot table sheets.

Answer (score 0):

i've made tons of dashboards. 
In my practice it depends in purpose. I use this rule:
1. Lable and id all your charts, like "1.1 Diagramm sales by month"
2. Try to use names for source pivot tables, like "sale_table_1"
3. Plan your screen space - draw a sketch of how wood dashboard look like at the end, depending on user use stories (how would them use it). Try to keep all you need in 1 17' display screen. 
4. Put all data calculations seperatly.
5. Split data for different named sheets if it is hard to navigate between tables and pivots
6. Finaly it is good to make a navigation page with links to different pages, like: "linkto:sheet with sales data" so on

Hop you find it usefull